# Edit models with complex primary key with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm having a trouble with opening AA edit-page for a model, which has a lot of associations.

What I had it's like 50 selects, opening at once. And this page turns to be deadly slow.

After reading this [ActiveAdmin: How to handle large associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195877/activeadmin-how-to-handle-large-associations) I considered to use select2 instead of usual select, but things get even worse.

That was because most of the time Rails spent in generating views, not in querying database. So with fancy select2 it reasonably spends even more time in views.

With that knowledge in mind, I decided to not have select inputs on that page at all. So I'll edit "main" object on that slow page, but connected with has_and_belongs_to_many objects should be edited separately.

But after that decision I've faced with a trouble: how should I edit tables with a complex primary key: not just id, but `:person_id` and `:organization_id`.

AA by default generates urls like that: `/admin/person_organizations/:id/edit`, but I need something like this: `/admin/person_organizations/:person_id/:organization_id/edit`

Any ideas?

Comment: try manual routing "GET    /admin/person_organizations/:person_id/:organization_id/edit => person_organizations#edit"

Comment: thanks, Ali, somehow I've missed that simple way to "fix" auto-generated routes :D

Comment: well, don't seem to be a solution here though. I was trying to add a ```member_action :edit2``` and point custom route to it, but it seems to be impossible also, since ```member_action``` creates it's own route like ```/admin/person_organizations/:id/edit2```(again, no second part of the key here). Could you please be little bit more concrete, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin should be able to handle custom primary keys by default. Just be sure that you add the definition to your model like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'person_id'
end
```

Comment: Well seems like I didn't explain well enough, but I have no problem with key names (person_id instead of just id), but it's about complex primary key, when I have table with primary key consists of two fields.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I've decided that I don't even need to have multiple keys here since Rails generates artificial `id` field for habtm tables. And as my goal was to edit this table, I've finished with standard ways of doing this.