# Big select in relation 'has many' - freezing browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have problem with freezing browser, when generating page in active admin.

When relation have 10-300 users everything was fine, now we have 30k and browser freezing.. How can I fix this ? Any solutions ? Maybe search field or sth ?

```
f.inputs "Users in app" do
  f.has_many :app_for_new_users do |p|
    p.input :new_user,:include_blank => true,:collection => User.all.order(name: :asc).all.map{|user, code| [(user.name.to_s + " | " + user.email.to_s) , user.id]}
   end
  end
```

Comment: I think using `map` is slowing your request down, try to concatenate the name and email in the query itself and then retrieve the data you need with `select` query method, so you don't need another processing after the data is retrieved. `User.all.order(name: :asc).select("(users.name | users.email) AS name_email", "users.id")`

Comment: maybe yo can use a select with ajax like https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Answer (score 2):

This is a [well known issue](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2692) that has come up on [StackOverflow before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195877/activeadmin-how-to-handle-large-associations). A popular solution is [holyketzer's plugin](https://github.com/holyketzer/activeadmin-ajax_filter).

Comment: Thanks, that's grate gem :)
But how can I limit fields returning by filter query ? Now its return every field in user model - this is not safe..